# Links in internet explorer mobile

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-mobile, windows-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile to develop a mobile website the problem is that links don't work in Internet explorer mobile

```
<a rel="external" href="http://www.external-site.com" title="" class="ui-link" style="text-decoration: none; ">
```

that is how the link looks i tried also with:

```
<a data-role="none" href="http://www.external-site.com" title="" class="ui-link" style="text-decoration: none; ">
```

I am wondering how are the links to external domains supposed to look to be able to work in windows mobile internet explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try linking the page like this:

```
<a data-role="none" href="http://www.google.com" class="ui-link" rel="external"  style="text-decoration: none; ">Multi-page link</a>
```

There is a chapter aboout linking pages in jQuery mobile docs. Have you read those?
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/link-formats.html

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

Based on this question:
[jquery Mobile urls add # tag which breaks forms in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737925/jquery-mobile-urls-add-tag-which-breaks-forms-in-internet-explorer)
Setting data-ajax="false" should help.

Comment: Yest i have read it and  i have tried the examples.As i said the problem is specific for internet explorer mobile

Comment: I already tried the data-ajax option and apparently it doesnt help

I have table in my <a> element
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>                    
                        <img  class="promoImage" src="/Content/Images/Promotions/<%= Model[i].PromotionImage %>" alt="<%= Model[i].PromotionTitle %>" />                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="greyText" style="text-align:left;">
                        <%= Model[i].PromotionTitle%>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

Comment: and that is what is causing the problem can you give me advice what to do

Comment: Simple way out may be handling click in javascript and setting window.location.href :P